# Can I upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard to SQL Server 2014 Developer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, migration, installation, sql-server-2014

Is there a migration path to upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard to SQL Server 2014 Developer?

If so, are there any pain points?

If not, how would you recommend I proceed?

The context of this question is a Developer machine that is running SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard and wants to now run SQL Server 2014 Developer.

**Update 07/11/2014** - The accepted answer worked for me. I installed SQL Server 2014 Developer as a named instance then followed [Zasz's StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026/sql-server-convert-a-named-instance-to-default-instance) to convert the named instance to the default instance.

Comment: As a side note/question, why are you trying to go from a Standard edition instance to a Developer edition instance?  That's not common.

Comment: @ThomasStringer Previously Standard edition was purchased for developers, however it seems that the Developer edition is more appropriate & management decided to go with that for the developers.

Comment: I hope you are aware developer edition cannot be used in production. Standard can be used.

Comment: @Shanky Yes the context of this question was for a developer's machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is [not a supported upgrade path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx).

> how would you recommend I proceed?

My recommendation would be to **install side-by-side** and then **migrate** (backup and restore) your databases to the SQL Server 2014 instance.

Comment: This worked for us.